(Alternative) proof that an invariant subspace is also invariant under the semisimple part
I'm stuck on this little part of a proof where I have an endomorphism $x$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ (over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, though that shouldn't matter) leaves a subspace $W \subseteq V$ invariant. Studying the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of $x$ ($x = s + n$ with $s$ semisimple, $n$ nilpotent and $[sn]=0$), I need to prove that $s$ also stabilizes $W$.
Most literature does this by showing that $s = p(x)$ for $p$ a polynomial with no free term using the Chinese Remainder Theorem before even getting to this property. However, I've avoided this theorem because it would make my proof considerably longer and I have already proved all other properties of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition without it. Is there an elegant way to do this without the Chinese Remainder Theorem? I've mainly been using linear algebra and the decomposition of $V$ by generalized eigenspaces.
So far, all I have is that, if there's a vector $v \in W$ with $s(v) \notin W$ and $n^r(v) = 0$, then we have an infinite sequence of (not linearly independent) vectors $s^r(v), s^{r+1}(v), \dots, \in W$ that are linearly independent to $v$. (and some more properties of this sequence from all my grasping at straws)
With this, I need to find a contradiction. Likely something that implies that $x(v) \notin W$, that $s$ is not semisimple or something along these lines, but my brain is fried right now.
I am very aware that I just need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to prove that there's a polynomial with no free term such that $p(x)$ is the semisimple part of $x$ and that's probably what I will end up doing, but I am just wondering if there's a way to avoid this. Thank you.

Okay i was just complicating everything by myself over and over last night. I just completely ignored this proof:
If $x(W) \subseteq W$, we can decompose $W$ in generalized eigenspaces
$$W_i = \left\{ v \in W \mid \exists r \in \mathbb N, (x - \lambda_i I)^r(v) = 0 \right\} = W \cap V_i$$
where $V_i$ are the corresponding generalized eigenspaces of x as an endomorphism of $V$.
Then $W = (W \cap V_i) \oplus \cdots \oplus (W \cap V_m)$. Because $s \vert_{V_i} = \lambda_i I$ where $I$ is the identity, we have that and $s(W \cap V_i) \subseteq W \cap V_i$, so $s(W) \subseteq W$.
